# C++ libcurl IMAP fetch header fields

Tags: c++, curl, imap, libcurl

I am using libcurl with IMAP to fetch messages from an email inbox. I can fetch messages completely, but I am unable to fetch a header field; my writefunction for curl only returns the first line.

Here is my code:

```
std::string fetchdata;

size_t write_data(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up) {
    fetchdata.append((char*)buf, size*nmemb);
    return size*nmemb;
}

int fetchmail() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "myemail@gmail.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "mypassword");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "UID FETCH 10 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (To)]");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",

        curl_easy_strerror(res));        
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    std::ofstream outfile("C:\\Path\\fetched.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    outfile << fetchdata;
    outfile.close();

    return (int)res;
}
```

Running `fetchmail` outputs

```
* 3 FETCH (UID 10 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (To)] {29}
```

in fetched.txt. However, this is only the first line; the console outputs

```
* 3 FETCH (UID 10 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (To)] {29}
To: laboutpost3@gmail.com

)
A004 OK Success
```

If I modify `write_data()` to

```
size_t write_data(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up) {
    fetchdata.append((char*)buf, size*nmemb);
    std::cout << buf;
    return size*nmemb;
}
```

it outputs

```
* 3 FETCH (UID 10 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (To)] {29
To: laboutpost3@gmail.com

)
A004 OK Success
ted. (Success)
 (Success)
 (Success)
WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)
[UIDNEXT 12] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1759]
A003 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1759]
A003 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)
```

Is this a problem with my `write_data()`? `buf` seems to have all the information.

Comment: The `buf` parameter in the `write_data()` function is not null-terminated, but `cout << buf;` requires that.  You are printing the content of surrounding memory. The buffer is just raw bytes, that is why you are given the buffer size as another parameter.

Comment: You could, or you could use a temp `std::string` instead: `cout << string(buf, size*nmemb);`

Comment: But the buffer contains what I need, it seems that `write_data()` is passed the wrong size?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want the stuff after the first line, just not all of it.

Comment: Since you are using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, curl has no choice but to give you the server's entire reply, as it has no context to know what the request is or how to process the reply for you. You will have to parse the reply yourself if you want to extract smaller portions of it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is there another way to give IMAP commands? And is the entire `buf` the servers output?

Comment: You might want to look at curl's documentation and examples, in particular the `UID` and `SECTION` parameters of an IMAP URL, eg: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX/;UID=10/;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(To)");`. That will generate an appropriate `FETCH` without you having to use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`. Read [RFC 5092](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5092) for the full syntax of an IMAP url.

Comment: And curl will give as many buffers as it takes to give you an entire reply. It may give you 1, it may give you many, it depends on the size of the reply and how curl reads it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! I will accept if you post answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `buf` parameter in the `write_data()` function is not null-terminated, but calling `cout << buf` requires a null terminator since `buf` is a `char*` pointer.  As such, you are printing the content of surrounding memory. The `buf` data is just raw bytes, that is why you are given the buffer size as another parameter.  When printing `buf`, you have to take that size into account, eg:

```
std::cout << std::string(buf, size*nmemb);
```

Alternatively:

```
std::cout.write(buf, size*nmemb);
```

Since you are using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, curl sends the request as-is and gives you back the server's reply as-is.  In that situation, curl has no context to know what the request is or how to process the reply for you.  You will have to parse the reply yourself if you want to extract smaller portions of it.

You might want to look at curl's documentation and examples, in particular use the `UID` and `SECTION` parameters of an IMAP url (Read [RFC 5092](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5092) for the full syntax), eg:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX/;uid=10/;section=HEADER.FIELDS%20(To)");
```

That will allow curl to generate its own `FETCH` request without you having to resort to using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` manually.  Since curl is creating the `FETCH` request, it is more likely to parse the response for you, giving just the requested header data to your `write_data()` function so it has less to parse/strip manually.

Comment: Just so others don't stumble over this: curl interprets the ";uid=XXX" parameter as a message number, not an IMAP UID as per specification. IOW, the URL variant will issue an simple FETCH, rather than a UID FETCH.